# Web Interface For Visualizing ASP.NET Performance Counters Remotely

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-ec2, performancecounter, appharbor

Is there an ELMAH equivalent for performance monitoring (e.g. something you can plug into an ASP.NET app so you can visualize performance counters remotely)?

There are some solutions for Azure but I'm wondering if there is something more generic that can be deployed to places like AppHarbor:

- http://blog.ehuna.org/2009/12/visualizing_windows_azure_diag_1.html
- http://www.samuraiprogrammer.com/blog/CommentView,guid,3acb3cdd-ccc7-4e87-a812-da7b080682a6.aspx

Comment: If this is something you think AppHarbor should add, you can create a post on the AppHarbor Feedback Forum (http://appharbor.com/feedback).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'd ever be able to access Performance Counters in medium trust, so having AppHarbor add this functionality is probably the only way it'd work.

Also bear in mind that your app may be running across multiple instances so the counters would be different per instance (and I'm not sure if you could easily get them from each one, since you don't see to have any control over which instance your request goes to).

Finally, you're probably not the only person on an EC2 instance, so only counters you could restrict to your applications process would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

ELMAH should work fine on Azure too. Also you can try defining manually some performance counters and then copying them to the diagnostics storage. More about Diagnostics on Azure can be found in the Windows Azure BootCamp [materials](http://windowsazurebootcamp.com/materials), Diagnostics and Service Management presentation. Then you can use Cerebrata Diagnostic Manager tool to see them. The tool is available [here](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/Default.aspx)